# Custom Connection Pool Using Java

Tags: java

I have built this very simple Connection Pool in Java Using Factory pattern. My thought here was to try on 2 connection Types e.g. SQL and NoSQL. Please review and suggest if my approach is fine. I am trying my hands on Java design patterns, so your review will help me to see where I need to improve in my design process.

**Connection class**

```java
// very basic definition
public interface Connection {

    UUID getMarker();
    boolean commit();
    void close();

}
```

**JdbcConnection class**

```java
public class JdbcConnection implements Connection {

    private Credentials credentials;
    private HostInfo hostInfo;
    private UUID marker;

    public JdbcConnection(UUID marker, Credentials credentials, HostInfo hostInfo) {
        this.credentials = credentials;
        this.hostInfo = hostInfo;
        this.marker = marker;
    }

    public UUID getMarker() {
        return marker;
    }

    public boolean commit() {
        return true;
    }

    public void close() {
        System.out.println("["+ this.marker+ "] is renewed for next connection");
        this.marker = UUID.randomUUID();
    }
}
```

**ConnectionFactory class**

```java
public final class ConnectionFactory {

    private ConnectionFactory() {
    }

    public static Connection get(ConnectionType type, DbPoolconfig dbPoolconfig) {
        if (type.equals(ConnectionType.SQL)) {
            return new JdbcConnection(UUID.randomUUID(), dbPoolconfig.getCredentials(), dbPoolconfig.getHostInfo());
        }
        return new CassandraConnection(UUID.randomUUID(), dbPoolconfig.getCredentials(), dbPoolconfig.getHostInfo());

    }

}
```

**Pool class**

```java
public interface Pool<T> {
    T get() throws InterruptedException;
    void release(T object);
    void shutdown();
}
```

**DbConnectionPool class**

```java
public interface DbConnectionPool<T> extends Pool {
    int getAvailableConnections();
    int getBusyConnectionsCount();
}
```

**DbConnectionPoolManager class**

```java
public final class DbConnectionPoolManager implements DbConnectionPool {

    private static DbConnectionPoolManager instance;
    private DbPoolconfig dbPoolconfig;
    private BlockingQueue<Connection> pool;
    private Set<Connection> busy;

    public static DbConnectionPoolManager get(DbPoolconfig dbPoolconfig) {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (DbConnectionPoolManager.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    return new DbConnectionPoolManager(dbPoolconfig);
                }
            }
        }

        return instance;
    }

    private DbConnectionPoolManager(DbPoolconfig dbPoolconfig) {
        this.dbPoolconfig = dbPoolconfig;
        this.pool = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Connection>(dbPoolconfig.getMaxSize());
        this.busy = new HashSet<Connection>();
        init();
    }

    private void init() {

        int initial = dbPoolconfig.getIntialSize();
        for (int i = 0; i < initial; i++) {
            pool.offer(ConnectionFactory.get(dbPoolconfig.getType(), dbPoolconfig));
        }

    }

    public Connection createNew() {
        if (busy.size() == dbPoolconfig.getMaxSize()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Pool is full.. cannot issue connection");
        }
        Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.get(dbPoolconfig.getType(), dbPoolconfig);
        pool.offer(connection);
        return connection;
    }

    public Connection get() throws InterruptedException {
        Connection connection = null;
        if (pool.peek() == null && busy.size() < dbPoolconfig.getMaxSize()) {
            connection = createNew();
        } else {
            connection = pool.take();
        }

        this.busy.add(connection);
        return connection;
    }

    public void release(Object object) {
        if (object != null) {
            Connection connection = (Connection) object;
            connection.close();
            pool.offer(connection);
            this.busy.remove(connection);
        }
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        // clear connection and remove from queu
        while (!pool.isEmpty()) {
            Connection connection = null;
            try {
                connection = pool.take();
                connection.close();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public int getAvailableConnections() {
        return (dbPoolconfig.getMaxSize() - busy.size());
    }

    public int getBusyConnectionsCount() {
        return busy.size();
    }

}
```

**Test**

````java
public class DbConnectionPooMangerTest {
    DbConnectionPoolManager mgr;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        Credentials credentials = new Credentials("1", "2");
        HostInfo info = new HostInfo("sss", "sss");
        DbPoolconfig config = new DbPoolconfig(info, credentials, ConnectionType.SQL, 15, 2);
        mgr = DbConnectionPoolManager.get(config);
    }

    @Test
    public void testConnection() {
        int m = 40;
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(m);
        final List<Future<String>> conns = new ArrayList();

        Callable<String> callable = new Callable<String>() {
            public String call() throws Exception {
                try {
                    Connection con = mgr.get();
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 2));
                    mgr.release(con);
                    System.out.println("Available "+ mgr.getAvailableConnections());
                    System.out.println("Busy "+ mgr.getBusyConnectionsCount());
                    return (con.getMarker()) +"";
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            Future<String> f = service.submit(callable);
             conns.add(f);
        }

        int count = 0;
        for(Future<String> f : conns) {
            try {
                String s = f.get();
                System.out.println(s);
                if(s != null) {
                    count++;
                }
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();;
            }

        }

        Assert.assertEquals(m, count);
        service.shutdown();
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: Thanks Simon for this suggestion, I will follow going forward.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have started down a singleton approach, then changed your mind / not completed it.

```
private static DbConnectionPoolManager instance;

public static DbConnectionPoolManager get(DbPoolconfig dbPoolconfig) {
    if (instance == null) {
        synchronized (DbConnectionPoolManager.class) {
            if (instance == null) {
                return new DbConnectionPoolManager(dbPoolconfig);
            }
        }
    }

    return instance;
}
```

You never actually set `instance` to anything other than it's default value, so you're getting a new PoolManager every time you call `get`.  Is this by design?

Comment: Oops, Great catch! I missed assigned to 'instance', I will correct it.